# why is php's ini_set function switched off on shared hosts

Tags: php, set, shared, host, ini

I am using hosting on VPS and they've not allowed me to use php's ini_set function to set configuration at runtime, on a script by script basis. Instead I must change the settings directly in the php.ini file which is a mission to access via SSH.

Why is this?

This, although fine, is slightly annoying as I have 12 domains on the shared server and I do not neccessarily want to set the settings across the board....

Answer (score 2):

If it's a product aimed at resellers, it is probably to prevent *your* clients / customers / users from changing php.ini settings at will, which is usually a wise thing to do.

But if you have full access to the machine, shouldn't you be able to re-activate `ini_set`?

Answer (score 1):

Like Pekka said, if you can modify your php.ini via SSH, then try to change it there.

Turn off `safe_mode` and check for contents of `disable_functions`

> This directive allows you to disable certain functions for security reasons. It takes on a comma-delimited list of function names. disable_functions is not affected by Safe Mode. This directive must be set in php.ini For example, you cannot set this in httpd.conf.

Answer (score 0):

VPS providers have a tendency to *force* their users to use the most secure environment possible. Disabling `ini_set()` typically is good security practice, since you could easily have an `eval()` statement in your PHP code that uses a GET/POST/SESSION variable as input, for example. I believe `ini_set()` is blocked by default if `safe_mode` is turned on. I would imagine any shared hosting provider would enforce `safe_mode`.

Comment: Just to be clear: to use eval() AT ALL is bad practice. Never, ever, ever use user input for eval() if you need to use eval() at all, even with safe_mode on.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell more about the server components. PHP as CGI or mod_php. Is PHP enabled with suPHP or other protection systems?
Some option can be changed with an .htaccess file. Have you direct access to the httpd.conf file? There you can enable ini_set() -> http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php