# display_errors directive doesn't work

Tags: php

I wanted to switch off the errors on my website (production) using the classic functions error_reporting() and ini_set(). I finally realized it's not possible with my shared web server which hosts sites for free. It's altervista.org. I googled the web and found this is very common with many hosting servers.

Anyway I tried this, as in local with Xammp on my Ubuntu it works perfectly:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);  
ini_set('display_errors', 'off');  // In earlier versions, this directive was of type boolean, now is string
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);  
ini_set('log_errors', 1);  
ini_set('log_errors_max_len', 0);   
ini_set('ignore_repeated_errors', 1);  
ini_set('ignore_repeated_source', 1);  
ini_set('report_memleaks', 1);  
ini_set('track_errors', 1);  
ini_set('error_log', './error_log2');
 ?>
```

Can anybody confirm that thing? And also have a look at my code?

Thanks all in advance.

I want also to add that I have no access to the php.ini file of course, and I tried to use a .htaccess file with the right instructions too, but I solved nothing at all.

Guess there's nothing else to do but to use the error_reporting() the way it was said here below, that's:

error_reprting(0);

looks like it's the only thing to do.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095641/why-is-phps-ini-set-function-switched-off-on-shared-hosts) should probably answer your question.

Comment: you should use `error_reporting(0);`