# 200 OK. The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have a trouble with my PHP script. This script must parse XML-file in my MySQL database. It works perfectly in my localhost server, but when I upload it in my hosting server, script throw an error:

"OK
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, name@domain.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have
caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log."

I put this code:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
ini_set('set_time_limit', 0);
set_time_limit(0);
```

but the error appears again and again..

Please, help me.

Comment: Are you testing on shared hosting ? may be this can be the issue check out link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095641/why-is-phps-ini-set-function-switched-off-on-shared-hosts

Comment: No, I have a dedicated server.

Comment: I wrote to the support service. They said that from their side there are no restrictions, as it is a dedicated server.

Comment: did you checked Apache/server  logs ? can you share the error logged in that

Comment: ALso try 
if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
}

Comment: I can't check logs.. It is shown that they are empty.......

Comment: I added your code but error is not gone. Appeared again in about the same period of time.

Comment: can you share the screenshot of error ? and use phpinfo() function to check the config are same on server and local

Comment: Here is the screenshot:
http://avtoreal.acme-group.ru/design/ru/style/acme/images/1.png

Comment: Here is the screenshot:
avtoreal.acme-group.ru/design/ru/style/acme/images/1.png

Comment: phpinfo() is great. What to show?

Comment: use phpinfo after your ini_set and search in phpinfo o/p that your settings are applied (there will be 2 tables local and master , check that ini_set should be applied in local values. )? and as i saw the screenshot , it's say more error in server log. then you should configure your server to log errors  so, that you can know what exact the issue is. only after view the exact coding/logic error this issue can be solved.

Comment: I decided to break the script into separate files and sequentially run each. I hope that this will be the solution to my problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answers!